# Change Days to Dates in Timetable for Android

Tags: java, android

Here is code to show `Mon-Fri` . I do not want to show the `Days (Mon-Fri)`. I want to show the `Dates (DD-MMM-YYY)`. How can I change my code. Please help me take a look.Thanks.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter(res));
    if (day == 1)
    {
        int finalDay = 6;
        pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
    }
    else
    {
        int finalDay = day - 2;
        pager.setCurrentItem(finalDay);
    }

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
```

Here is the ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to show the dates like this:

```
String pattern="dd-MMM-yyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.applyPattern(pattern);
String format = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```